# Wordpress register_post_type Invalid post type

Tags: post-type

I am creating my own posts in wordpress however I have hit a little problem and im not sure how to fix it.

The below register_post_type creates an Invalid post type error.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'talent',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Talent' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'talent' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    )
);
}
```

it doesn't seem to like the word talent. If I change 'talent' to 'arist' it works. However it needs to be 'talent' for the URL. Ive checked on wordpress and using talent shouldn't cause any conflicts with default wordpress settings.

Comment: What happens when you use `talent`?

Comment: creates an Invalid post type error.

Comment: Tested your code and it works for me. Do you have a plugin installed which creates cpt's?

Comment: No I have no plugins installed. Could it be because it started off as artist? Now im trying to change it?

Comment: You need to check if did not maybe by change registered your post type twice. Just a thought

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error? Please update your question.

Comment: Make sure the post type name is not longer than 20 characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26029803/722036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get the "talent" post type to register, set the name to artist and then using the Rewrite option for the CPT e.g.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'talent' ),
```

That will give you the URL you desire

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but the answer did not work for me. In case anyone else finds this, make sure the post type title is not longer than 20 characters. That might be the issue and Wordpress will not care to let you know.

Credits go to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26029803/722036

Comment: Very nice find, spent a lot of time this morning trying to figure out why in the world my post type wouldn't register.